# Error converting data type varchar to float when splitting String

Tags: sql-server, database

I am trying to split a string however its of data type varchar so to throws an error saying it cannot be converted to a float. I have tried but cant find a solution. How can i can i do it.

```
(SELECT Value FROM dbo.SplitString('648-44-21001-13764 ', '-') WHERE Position = 3)
```

Comment: what exactly output you want ?

Comment: @HiteshThakor the last number

Comment: 13764 this number you want as a output ?

Comment: @HiteshThakor yes

Comment: can you show me SplitString() function code ?

Comment: `(SELECT Value FROM dbo.SplitString([Current CGI], '-') WHERE Position = 3) AS CI`  The **current CGI** has got 4 numbers and im trying to split it and its of type varchar. Thats the code.

Answer (score 0):

Check your Function **Value column return type**, it seems VARCHAR so You have to explicit convert it to float:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
(
    @String NVARCHAR(4000),
    @Delimiter NCHAR(1)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
(
    WITH Split(stpos,endpos)
    AS(
        SELECT 0 AS stpos, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String) AS endpos
        UNION ALL
        SELECT endpos+1, CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@String,endpos+1)
            FROM Split
            WHERE endpos > 0
    )
    SELECT 'Position' = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)),
        'Value' = SUBSTRING(@String,stpos,COALESCE(NULLIF(endpos,0),LEN(@String)+1)-stpos)
    FROM Split
)


SELECT CAST((SELECT Value FROM dbo.SplitString('648-44-21001-13764 ', '-') WHERE Position = 3)  AS FLOAT)
```

Comment: Yeah its of nvarchar type but still not converting it. Don't undwerstand why,

Comment: I have update answer and put split function script, please try it

Comment: `INSERT INTO [Table].[Ares].[CountryValues] VALUES (Current CGI, varchar(255),) `

Answer (score 0):

```
Create FUNCTION SplitString
```

(
      @Input NVARCHAR(MAX),
      @Character CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Output TABLE (
      Value NVARCHAR(1000),
      Position int
)
AS
BEGIN
      DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT,@Position int
      SET @Position = 0
      SET @StartIndex = 1
      IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
      BEGIN
            SET @Input = @Input + @Character
      END

```
  WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
  BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Value,Position)
        SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1),@Position

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
        set  @Position=@Position+1;
  END

  RETURN
  END
  GO
```

Comment: add this function in your database and try your query SELECT Value FROM SplitString('648-44-21001-13764 ', '-') WHERE Position = 3